# How to stop youtube-dl downloading audio after a certain amount of time?

Tags: python, timer, youtube, python-multiprocessing, youtube-dl

I'm using python and trying to get youtube-dl to timeout after 10 seconds of downloading a youtube video's audio, but none of the answers on stack overflow or elsewhere have worked for me. I usually download videos less than 10 minutes in length, and most of the time, youtube-dl downloads them instantly, but I am trying to create a workaround for the occasions when youtube-dl takes almost two minutes to download a short video. My basic strategy is as follows:

```
def download(): # downloads yt video audio via os.command and youtube-dl
    ...

p = Process(target=download())
p.start()
Timer(10, p.kill)
```

When I run this code, the youtube-dl audio download continues, even when the download time exceeds 10 seconds. I would appreciate any thoughts, insights, or solutions that anyone is able to offer!

Thanks! -teleriffr

Answer (score 0):

Your error here `p = Process(target=download())`. You need to give callable object to `target` parameter, but you don't do this, you calling the `download()` function directly. Return value of `download()` will be given to target parameter, however you don't want this, i think.

You need to modify it like ;

```
def download(): # downloads yt video audio via os.command and youtube-dl
    ...

p = Process(target=download)
p.start()
Timer(10, p.kill).start() #don't forget to call start() method
```

Note: `download()` function can return callable object, and you can use `Process(target=download())` but in this scenario you try to call  `download` func by subprocess, i think.